# How to set unique color for each labels of legends in stacked bar graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am Working on a large data set and trying to get some important information from the stacked bar chart but when I plotted it I noticed that colors of the label aren't unique and that is a big issue for me. My goal is to set a unique color for each label I did a lot of research before posting this question here for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389636/creating-over-20-unique-legend-colors-using-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1). But they aren't working, it's giving error `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_color_cycle'`

```py
# my dataset is big so I am providing its instance
#suppose I have data of few cites and their complaints 
city = ['NEW YORK', 'ASTORIA', 'BRONX', 'BRONX', 'ELMHURST', 'BROOKLYN',
       'NEW YORK', 'BRONX', 'KEW GARDENS', 'BROOKLYN']
complaints = ['Noise - Street/Sidewalk', 'Blocked Driveway', 'Blocked Driveway',
       'Illegal Parking', 'Illegal Parking', 'Illegal Parking',
       'Illegal Parking', 'Blocked Driveway', 'Illegal Parking',
       'Blocked Driveway']
# and from this I have created a stack bar chart
test2 = new_cutmr_df[['Complaint Type', 'City']]
cmpltnt_rela = test2.groupby(['City', 'Complaint Type']).size().unstack().fillna(0).plot(kind='bar', legend = True, stacked=True)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),ncol=2)
cmpltnt_rela.plot(figsize=(18,14))
```

whose graph looks something like this
[image]

where you can notice color repetition in legend

Comment: It would be better if you could provide 'test2' data

Comment: it's nothing it is just for creating dataframe type object where I added those columns well I added it in edit

Comment: You even repeat your `set_color_cycle` error message, while your linked post clearly writes 
"In more recent versions of mplib (1.5+), the set_color_cycle function has been deprecated in favour of ax.set_prop_cycle(color=[...]).". You didn't try to understand Ernest's hint in the comments to your question?

Comment: Did you at least try to replace `set_color_cyle` with `set_prop_cycle(color=...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set unique color for individual value of legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840519/how-to-set-unique-color-for-individual-value-of-legend)

Comment: yes it solved thanks