# How to use correct cmap colors in nested pie chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

How do I use the correct np.array of cmap that the inside colors correspond to shades of the outside colors in a nested pie chart in matplotlib?

I tried using different arrays of cmap, but I don't understand how the arrays get transformed into cmap colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y =np.array([17, 16, 10, 8 ,6, 5, 5, 4, 3,  17 ,2 ,1, 1, 3, 2 ])
x = np.array([74 ,21 ,5])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3

cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab20c")

outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap(np.array([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]))

ax.pie(x, radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(y, radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the inside colors to be shades of the outside colors (greenish, blueish and orangish), but I have no idea how to change them accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The `tab20c` colormap has 4 shades per hue. So it will not be possible to use that for 9 subcategories.

#### A. Extend the number of shades per hue

Taking the `categorical_cmap` from [matplotlib generic colormap from tab10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222585/matplotlib-generic-colormap-from-tab10/47232942#47232942) one get get more shades per hue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

def categorical_cmap(nc, nsc, cmap="tab10", continuous=False):
    if nc > plt.get_cmap(cmap).N:
        raise ValueError("Too many categories for colormap.")
    if continuous:
        ccolors = plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.linspace(0,1,nc))
    else:
        ccolors = plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.arange(nc, dtype=int))
    cols = np.zeros((nc*nsc, 3))
    for i, c in enumerate(ccolors):
        chsv = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(c[:3])
        arhsv = np.tile(chsv,nsc).reshape(nsc,3)
        arhsv[:,1] = np.linspace(chsv[1],0.25,nsc)
        arhsv[:,2] = np.linspace(chsv[2],1,nsc)
        rgb = matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb(arhsv)
        cols[i*nsc:(i+1)*nsc,:] = rgb       
    cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cols)
    return cmap

y =np.array([17, 16, 10, 8 ,6, 5, 5, 4, 3,  17 ,2 ,1, 1, 3, 2 ])
x = np.array([74 ,21 ,5])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3

cmap = categorical_cmap(3, 10)

outer_colors = cmap(np.array([0, 10, 20]))
ar = np.concatenate((np.arange(1,10), [13,15,17,19], [25,30]))
inner_colors = cmap(ar)

ax.pie(x, radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(y, radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### B. Use three different colormaps

Alternatively, one could use three different continuous colormaps, and take some of those colors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y =np.array([17, 16, 10, 8 ,6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 17 ,2 ,1, 1, 3, 2 ])
x = np.array([74 ,21 ,5])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3

cmap1 = plt.cm.Reds
cmap2 = plt.cm.Purples
cmap3 = plt.cm.Greens

outer_colors = [cmap1(.8), cmap2(.8), cmap3(.8)]
inner_colors = [*cmap1(np.linspace(.6, .1, 9)),
                *cmap2(np.linspace(.6, .2, 4)),
                *cmap3(np.linspace(.6, .2, 2))]

ax.pie(x, radius=1, colors=outer_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(y, radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors,
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could I ask you, how do you know the arrays in the first code snippets   `outer_colors = cmap(np.array([0, 10, 20]))
                                      ar = np.concatenate((np.arange(1,10), [13,15,17,19], [25,30])) `

Comment: There is not much to "know" really. It just takes out the color indices manually. Because each hue has 10 colors, the first 10 indices (0 to 9) are the ones for the first hue, the next (10 to 19) the ones from the second etc.