# Plotting two independent dimensions on a map: recommended approaches?

Tags: python, data-visualization, choropleth

I'd like to have a two-dimensional sequential color palettes, for example, for use in a choropleth map (I guess as a type of bivariate map).

So for example, maybe hue (to indicate one value) and saturation (to indicate the other, here I have in mind population size).

Is there an off-the-shelf palette that I can use for this? If not, is that because there a recommended alternative for visualizing this information?

Python-friendly answers are especially helpful but this is a bit more generic.

Comment: Since seaborn is of no use here (it's a package for drawing statstical plots), I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Seaborn comes with various color palettes which encode recommended practices like e.g. sequential color palettes. I am sure a lot of other plotting libraries do as well https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Comment: It can help you getting a list of colors, but that is not your problem, is it? Or if it is, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232942/4124317).

Comment: Not exactly, but it's not that far to go from a list to a grid and a grid of colors well-adapted for bivariate map is what I am interested in.